# Want Calendar on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, calendar

Hey i have developed android application . Now at this stage i want to create calendar in my application .
The problem that i am facing is there isn't any calendar in the emulator so I don't know what to do now. I googled about this problem but won't able to find the proper solution for it.
So if any one have solution about my problem do help me. 
Thanks for your time and more appreciate if help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry not to answer directly, but the fastest way to test your apps on android is a device. I barely use the emulator. You should consider doing so too.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: You'd need a physical device for each supported version of Android.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to create an android image. The "bare" Android image. Or the Android image with the google apis. If you use the google api option you get the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Install CalDAV adapter inside the emulator.